# Can QuickTime Pro convert .mpg to .mov?

Tags: windows, video, quicktime, video-editing, mov

I am thinking about purchasing [QuickTime Pro](http://www.apple.com/quicktime/extending/) for *Windows*, but I have not been able to find a list of video file formats that it takes as input.  Does QuickTime Pro for Windows convert .mpg files to .mov?  Thank you!

Comment: Any reason to? A .mov is basically just a MPEG container. With what Codec is the actual video encoded?

Comment: @Gerry  I am using [VideoMach](http://gromada.com/videomach/) on Windows to compile many bitmap files and it says that the Codec is "MPEG-1".  VideoMach does not directly export to **.mov**, unfortunately.

Comment: I'd suggest using standard MPEG4 containers, unless you have a specific reason for using .mov?

Comment: @Gerry  Thanks, my friend who is a Mac user sometimes has trouble playing **.mpg** files that I send him.  I am a Windows user, so I'm not exactly sure what goes wrong sometimes when he tries to play them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **does**. [Here](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP521) you can find a list of all the import and export formats QuickTime Pro 7.7 supports.